# ASP.NET MVC - cannot implicitly convert type char to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please am I having this error in my line of code

```
        public string RegistrationGuideline(string guidelineMessage)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(guidelineMessage))
        {
            var guideline_mess = _optionRepository.FindAll().Where(c => c.OPTION_NAME == "guideline_message").Single(c => c.OPTION_ONE == "guidelineMessage");//option_message.Where(c => c.Item2 == guidelineMessage);
            if (guideline_mess != null)
            {
                var guidelineMess = guideline_mess.OPTION_VALUE.FirstOrDefault();//guideline_mess.Select(c => c.Item3).FirstOrDefault();
                return guidelineMess;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Where have I got it wrong and do I resolve it

Comment: which line number you've got the error ?

Comment: return guidelineMess;

Comment: so , check the result that came out from the query in the previous  line , what its expected result !

Comment: return guidelineMess.ToString(); should fix it, but i would check why you returning char and not string, when setting guidlineMess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate that `OPTION_VALUE` is a string. When you do this:

```
var guidelineMess = guideline_mess.OPTION_VALUE.FirstOrDefault();
```

You are specifying to use the *first character* of that string. Keep in mind, string implements `IEnumerable<char>` so when you use LINQ on a string, it will return a sequence of `char`s. `FirstOrDefault()` will therefore return the first `char` of the string.

Best guess is that you meant to do

```
var guidelineMess = guideline_mess.OPTION_VALUE;
```